# How does a javascript tooltip work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-ajax, tooltip

I just wanted to make a tooltip of my own[custom] and checkout how it goes. Shockingly it didn't get the results i wanted.
I wanted the tooltip to follow my mouse but ended something different. Below is the code with methods using asp.net ajax.

`<div id="grid_alertlist" class="add_config_container shadows gradient"><div id="tooltip" style="background-color:Black;></div></div>`

```
 Sys.Application.add_init(appLoaded);    
    function appLoaded(src,args){
    $addHandler($get("grid_alertlist"),"mousemove",hover);
    }

    function hover(evnt){
    div = $get("tooltip");
    div.style.display = "block";
    div.offsetLeft = evnt.screenX+'px';div.offsetTop = evnt.screenY+'px';
    }
```

code 1 is markup , code 2 is javascript. I attached a mousemove event handler to the `grid_alert_list` and made the `tooltip` follow my mouse. The `div#tooltip` moves around but not following the mouse pointer.
Could i know the workings of tooltip. I seen code where this requires some mathematics like `offsetTop/2` etc.

1.I Would like to know what is the reason behind it.

2.How to make the `div#tooltip` follow my mouse pointer with some padding

3.Some mistakes, precautions to take during development.

Comment: checkout https://github.com/effata/tipsy

Comment: @James sorry no jquery please. Just for tooltip i don't want to include jquery and tooltip plugin into the project

Comment: Why did you tag your question with jQuery then?

Comment: @James because as i mentioned in my question, i had look into the code of some of the plugins for jQuery doing this. As reference i had to do it, unintentionally it lured jquery lovers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

screenX is the mouse position relative to the whole screen. You'll need clientX/Y which is the  mouse position relative to the document.

Here's an example of the difference:
http://jsfiddle.net/PEZRH/ , http://jsbin.com/isico4/edit

---

```
$('div').mousemove(function(ev) {
    $(this).html(ev.screenX + ":" + ev.screenY + "<br/>" + ev.clientX + ":"
    + ev.clientY);
});
```

Comment: could you paste that on jsBin. jsFiddle seems to be blocked work place fireWall. Is clientX and clientY enough for this?